# Detecting the onion co-ordinates in an onion field

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

Due to lack of data, I have been asked to implement a non-data driven approach to find the co-ordinates of the onions in the onion field. The image would be an elevated front view.

Here is the image of an Onion Field:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
img = cv2.imread("/content/Onion1.jpeg",0)
img_blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
edges = cv2.Canny(img_blur,150,200)
```

The final output obtained:

[image: Output]

What are the ways through which I can do better to achieve the objective i.e. to find out the co-ordinates of the onions in the image?
Can we somehow take the advantage that onions are planted in rows or some other obvious fact that I am clearly missing?
Any help/advice is highly appreciated. Also, note that I am very new to OpenCV.

Edit : I have been able to isolate the green but am struggling to perform multiple template matching in order to find the peaks or peak co-ordinates.

Here is the output I got by separating the hue corresponding to green:
[image: Output]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
## Read
img = cv2.imread("/content/Onion1.jpeg")
img = cv2.blur(img, (10,10))
cv2_imshow(img)


## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
# mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255,255))
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255,255))

## slice the green
imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
green[imask] = img[imask]

## show
cv2_imshow(green)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('/tp.png',0) # tp is just a screenshot taken of one of the peaks
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(green, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2_imshow(green)
```

How can I generalise this peak detection so that it is a bit more robust?

Comment: You cannot count them if they are obscured. You may know how many columns and possibly the separation, but you do not know how rows per column

Comment: What's the desired output? Only the first row?  Which accuracy needed?

Comment: @Micka The desired output would be the co-ordinates of the onion in the first row. A high confidence answer is what is needed since we nee to feed this information to the autonomous robot which will then harvest this onion. The robot's tool has a span hence there is a chance that it crushes the onion at some adjacent row if not controlled properly. I hope you get the problem statement. Do let me know if you still have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: @fmw42 I am only interested in finding the co-ordinates of the onions in the very first row. I am not so concerned with what is happening behind the first row. Separation btw two onions can also help me. But co-ordinates would have been better.

Comment: from that distance you can't see squat. engineer this so the camera is a lot closer. -- are you really outsourcing autonomous robotics to stack overflow? why not hire someone? it's clearly a commercial application and you aren't asking "how does this API work" but "how do I solve my business proposition"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling that detecting the green color can be a good starting point.

In the picture below, the Hue component has been used and clearly shows the distinction between the vegetation and the soil. The next step would be to find the peaks, which can be robustly achieved by grayscale correlation. (We used the second peak as the template and found the other three; the figures are matching scores.)

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7uVJ.png)

[image]

Now the onions could be more precisely located by some local search near the tip of the peaks.

Comment: Exactly same as my idea, but I didn't find the time to try it :)

Comment: @Yves Daoust Would it be possible to share the code? This seems exactly like what I am looking for? I thank you for you time.

Comment: @codeWITHswap: sorry, made with proprietary software. Conversion to HLS and template matching.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classification using k-means, which finds the onions, because they are clearly differentiated by his color, but this will not work with other photographs in general.

It separates the image in `numClustersToIdentify = 4` different colors

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


def downloadImage(URL):
    """Downloads the image on the URL, and convers to cv2 BGR format"""
    from io import BytesIO
    from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
    import requests

    response = requests.get(URL)
    image = PIL_Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


URL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVS6X.jpg"

# Read image
im = downloadImage(URL)


# types of colors to be detected
numClustersToIdentify = 4

# classify the image in types of colors
linearImg = im.reshape((im.shape[1]*im.shape[0], 3))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=numClustersToIdentify)
s = kmeans.fit(linearImg)
imgLabels = s.labels_.reshape(im.shape[0], im.shape[1]).astype(np.uint8)
imgLabels = cv2.normalize(imgLabels, None, 0, 255,
                          cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)

cv2.imshow("Image", im)
cv2.waitKey(10)
cv2.imshow("Labels", imgLabels)
cv2.waitKey(10)

columns = 3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    math.ceil(numClustersToIdentify/columns), columns, squeeze=False)

for i, label in enumerate(np.unique(imgLabels)):
    ax[i//columns, i % columns].imshow(imgLabels == label)
    ax[i//columns, i % columns].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Will I get a reproducible output every time? Also there is a bit of noises i.e. other white patches. Can they be removed? Finally, how can I find the co-ordinates of the onion from this image?

Comment: k-means is not guaranteed to produce the same result every time. Here the onions are on the second image, but the order may change. You may detect the coordinates (on the image) with blob detection, which gives the center of the blobs.